# SASS group elements for reuse

Tags: css, sass

I want to create a 'group' of elements that get certain colours/styles added to them based on the body class.

I'm using SASS and don't want to have to write the same elements each time.

I know the the code below is wrong but you get the idea.

Is something like this possible?

```
@mixin coloured-elements {
    a:hover,
    a.site-title,
    .another-element
}
body.blue {
    @include coloured-elements {
        color: $blue;
    }
}
body.green {
    @include coloured-elements {
        color: $green;
    }
}
body.red {
    @include coloured-elements {
        color: $red;
    }
}
body.purple {
    @include coloured-elements {
        color: $purple;
    }
}
body.orange {
    @include coloured-elements {
        color: $orange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make coloured-elements accept arguments and then define a colors list, iterate and dynamically create everything. Something like:

```
@mixin coloured-elements($color) {
  a:hover, a.site-title, .another-element {
    color: $color
  }
}

$colors: blue, red, purple, orange;

@each $color in $colors {
  body.#{$color} {
    @include coloured-elements($color);
  }
}
```

Please note that I didn't transpile this, you might need to adjust it. Check the docummentation to properly do it.

If you provide a codepen, I can edit the answer.

Edit:

1. [sass lists](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists)
2. [sass hashmaps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) if you want to use this data structure
3. [Control directives](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives__expressions)
4. [Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: This is great too. I like the idea of defining a colours list then re-using it as a mixin.

Comment: Can I ask why the hash is needed `body.#{$color}`

Comment: Well I'd say that this is DRY and idiomatic. If you want to introduce a new color, you just need to define it and add it to a list. If you change the structure and use a hash map and also change the iterator, you'll have a dictionary of colors :)

Comment: `#{ }` is used in rails (and sass) to interpolate. `.` means class. `.#{$color}` when `$color` is `red` => `.red`

Comment: @radubogdan what if my elements using that variable are large in numbers. I can't define them in a single mixin

Comment: You can have multiple mixins with single responsability. I'm not sure I get your use case, can you add an edit to your question?

Comment: @radubogdan Just an update. How would I do this for variable colours (ie. not simple 'blue' or 'red' but '$primary' or '$blue'?

Comment: `$primary` and `$blue` are variables. You can define an array of already defined variables, hence `$colors: $primary, $blue`

Answer (score 1):

Check out using & after an element to select 'is a child of'.

```
.element1,
.element2 {
  body.orange & {
    color: orange;
  }
  body.blue & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks... couldn't see the forest for the trees

Comment: There are probably a few other nice alternative ways of doing this. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass content to a mixin you should use @content:

```
@mixin coloured-elements {
    a:hover,
    a.site-title,
   .another-element { @content; }
}
```

In your example (using the above mixin) you'll get the following output:

```
body.blue a:hover,
body.blue a.site-title,
body.blue .another-element {
  color: blue;
}

body.green a:hover,
body.green a.site-title,
body.green .another-element {
  color: green;
}

body.red a:hover,
body.red a.site-title,
body.red .another-element {
  color: red;
}

body.purple a:hover,
body.purple a.site-title,
body.purple .another-element {
  color: purple;
}

body.orange a:hover,
body.orange a.site-title,
body.orange .another-element {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@each` and `#{}` interpolation for that. Create the `$valiable`s with *selectorName*, *colorValue* pairs and then put them into `@each` directive after `in` keyword as in example below. The pairs solve the problem of using different selector names and color values, eg. `.red {color: #f00};` instead `.red{color:red}`

```
$blue: blue, #42a5f5;
$green: green, #66bb6a;
$red: red, #f44336;
$purple: purple, #ba68c8;
$orange: orange, #f57c00;

a:hover, a.site-title, .another-element {
   @each $selector, $color in $blue, $green, $red, $purple, $orange {
      body.#{$selector} {
          color: $color;
      }
   }
}
```

The CSS result will be:

```
a:hover body.blue, a.site-title body.blue, .another-element body.blue {
  color: #42a5f5; 
}

a:hover body.green, a.site-title body.green, .another-element body.green {
  color: #66bb6a;
}
```

...etc.