# Change all variable value based on body class

Tags: css, sass

I am working on theme based localisation. For that I am getting class on body tag for each localisation.
I need to change all variables value based on that class
For more Understanding

```
$a: #000;
$b= Arial;

if body has class Australia then
$a: #ff0000;
$b: 'Roboto';
```

Please no js code only by scss

Comment: So pretty much the same as in this question that was asked an hour earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249085/sass-group-elements-for-reuse

Comment: I checked that question but was not helpful. it mention for a certain group of elements. but for me I need it for the whole website. These variables are used multiple times in multiple classes.

Answer (score 3):

**Using @import and !default variables**

```
// –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– 
// _style.scss 
// underscore added to prevent compilation 
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$color      : red   !default;
$font-family: Arial !default; 

.foo { color: $color; }
.bar { font-family: $font-family; }



// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// style.scss (compile file) 
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// redefine variables
$color: blue;
$font-family: Roboto;

// add wrapper if needed (will be added to all selectors)
.australia {
    @import '_style.scss';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses a map to define different theme values. The mixin will wrap each selector in a class (the map key) and create global variables to be used inside each selector.

```
$theme-map:(
  '.australia': (color: blue, font-family: Roboto),
  '.denmark'  : (color: red,  font-family: Arial)    
);


@mixin theme {
  @each $class, $map in $theme-map {
    #{$class} & { 
      $color:       map-get($map, color)       !global;
      $font-family: map-get($map, font-family) !global;
      @content;
    }
  }
}



.foo {
  @include theme {
    color: $color;
    font-family: $font-family;
  }
}


.bar{
  @include theme {
    background-color: $color;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.australia .foo {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.denmark .foo {
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.australia .bar {
  background-color: blue;
}
.denmark .bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

PS. in the near future CSS variables will ease this type of work using  variable inheritance.

```
.australia {
   --color: red;
   --font-family : Arial;
}

.denmark {
   --color: blue;
   --font-family : Roboto;
}



.foo {
   color: var(--color);
   font-family: var(--font-family);
}

.bar {
   backgound-color: var(--color);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to edit each selector. Cause there are thousands of selector using those variable.Editing each will take a whole life..

Comment: In that case maybe use @import and !default variables – I'll add a new example. Also note the updated section about CSS variables