# Materialize primary-color override depending on body class

Tags: class, sass, overriding, materialize

Hi all *(first post be indulgent ^^)*,

I'm using materializecss in a project. 
I already override the $primary-color like this

```
@import "~materialize-css/sass/components/color";

$primary-color: color("green", "accent-4") !default;
$secondary-color: $primary-color;

@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize";
```

Now, depending on a body class I need to override the $primary-color to the ones I defined previously.

```
// Patho palette
$patho-pink:        color('pink', 'darken-1'); //#d81b60
$patho-amber:       color('amber', 'accent-4'); //#ffab00
$patho-lime:        color('lime', 'darken-1'); //#c0ca33
$patho-green:       color('green', 'darken-1');// #43a047
$patho-teal:        color('teal', 'accent-4'); //#00897b
$patho-light-blue:  color('light-blue', 'darken-3'); //#0277bd
$patho-deep-purple: color('deep-purple', 'lighten-1'); //#7e57c2
$patho-purple:      color('purple', 'lighten-2'); //#ba68c8
$patho-red:         color('red', 'accent-2'); //#ff5252
```

knowing that I have 9 classes that can be added to the body.

```
<body class="patho-pink">...</body>
<body class="patho-amber">...</body>
<body class="patho-lime">...</body>
<body class="patho-green">...</body>
<body class="patho-teal">...</body>
<body class="patho-light-blue">...</body>
<body class="patho-deep-purple">...</body>
<body class="patho-purple">...</body>
<body class="patho-red">...</body>
```

I've seen some [creating mixin and map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250583/change-all-variable-value-based-on-body-class) but the override doesn't work for me. I might be doing it wrong, I don't know. Jakob ([2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251846/9977432)) use a mapping :

```
$theme-map:(
  '.australia': (color: blue, font-family: Roboto),
  '.denmark'  : (color: red,  font-family: Arial)    
);
```

I need that kind of solution but for variables since here I need to map the $primary-color not a css property (color, font-family here).

The idea is to create a predefined css like :

```
.patho-red{
   $primary-color: $patho-red;
}
.patho-pink{
   $primary-color: $patho-pink;
}
...
```

and output the right css for all of my 9 classes in order to have the primary override by adding the class to the body (and all materialize variables using the $primary-color should be impacted by this override).

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you [edit] your qestion to specify more clearly how the linked answer does not help you? What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: @Ralf Thank you :) Edited, hope it helps ! I've tried to change css properties for variables but i guess it can't be done this way. I surely can do this with css variables but not supported by all browsers ATM so not a solution for me.