# SCSS Mixin Using Root-Relative Selector

Tags: angular, sass

What I am currently implementing is a light and dark mode in an Angular App (Angular 11) using SCSS. I know how to set up the themes, and apply the relevant classes to some root element (`app-root` to switch between the themes. I am looking for a clean way to style an element (like an arbitrary div) with a background color that changes based on light and dark mode.

So I have backgrounds defined like

```
$light-bg-1: white;
$light-bg-2: mat-color($mat-grey, 50);
$light-bg-3: mat-color($mat-grey, 300);

$light-bg-1: mat-color($mat-grey, 900);
$light-bg-2: mat-color($mat-grey, 800);
$light-bg-3: mat-color($mat-grey, 700);
```

and a class on the `app-root` that is either `.app-light-theme` or `.app-dark-theme`

### What I *want* to be able to do.

```
// In global/shared partials
@mixin bg1() { 
  // uses $light-bg-1 or $light-bg-2 for background-color based on
  // which class is applied on the app-root.
}

// In blah.component.scss
#blah-element {
   ...
   @include bg1();
}
```

### Other ways that (I think) would work but looking for best solution

#### Don't use a mixin and just define classes

```
.app-light-theme .bg1 { background-color: $light-bg-1; } 
.app-dark-theme .bg1 { background-color: $dark-bg-1; }
```

but would rather not have to do `<div id="blah-element" class="bg1">`

#### Mixin included outside of the element's selector that include the elements selector

Something like

```
// In global/shared partials
@mixin bg1($selector) { 
  .app-dark-theme #{$selector} { background-color: $dark-bg-1};
  .app-dark-theme #{$selector} { background-color: $dark-bg-2};
}

// In blah.component.scss
@include bg1(#blah-element);
#blah-element {
   ...
}
```

---

Comment: You might read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666411/14036853). You'd need to modify the selectors a little, but it'd basically do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was essentially looking for the `:host-context` psuedo-selector. I used this in a mixin like defined below:

```
@mixin bg-0($selector) {
  :host-context(.app-theme-light) #{$selector} { background-color: $light-bg-0; }
  :host-context(.app-theme-dark) #{$selector} { background-color: $dark-bg-0; }
}
```

Then opted to use the `&` parent selector to pass as a parameter to the mixin:

```
#blah-component {
    @include bg-0(&);
}
```